# eslint undefined named imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I keep running into issues with `undefined` named imports.  If I mistype the path or filename while importing a named import, I'm not warned.  Then my named import is equal to `undefined` and it short circuits my reducer or causes some other hard-to-trace problem.

Is there any way to configure eslint to complain about `undefined` imports?

```
import { MISSPELLED_CONSTANT } from './constants'

export const myReducer = (state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case MISPELLED_CONSTANT:
      return doSomething(state);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Later on in another file:

`expect(myReducer(undefined, {})).toEqual(initialState)`

fails because of the bad import.

Comment: *"If if mistype the path or filename while importing a named import..."* First off, slight chuckle at a typo in a sentence asking about typos. But a significant question as well: You've said the issue is misspelling the path or filename, but in the code snippet, the issue is that you're not using what you've imported. You're using `MISPELLED_CONSTANT`, but importing `MISSPELLED_CONSTANT`. Can you clarify which thing you're asking about?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good catch on the typo.  I guess it's more of a problem with misspelling the _name_ of a named import.  e.g. importing `MISPELLED_CONSTANT` when I should be importing `MY_CONSTANT`.

Comment: Sorry, still not getting it. Could you update the question to say whether the problem is the `import` statement or the `case` statement? If the former, I'd expect both uses to be spelled the same way.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import ?

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, that looks like exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the issue is with the import. `MISPELLED_CONSTANT` was never exported from `./constants`. 
From the npm package @FelixKling mentioned I want to _"Ensure named imports correspond to a named export in the remote file."_